# How do I get the current interrupt state (enabled, disabled or current level) on a MC9S12ZVM processor

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

I'm working on a project using a MC9S12ZVM family processor and need to be able to get, save and restore the current interrupt enabled state.  This is needed to access variables from the main line code that may be modified by the interrupt handler that are larger than word in size and therefore not atomic.

pseudo code: (variable is 32bits and -= isn't atomic anyhow)

```
state_save = current_interrupt_state();
DisableInterrupt();
variable -= x;
RestoreInterrupts(state_save);
```

Edit: I found something that works, but has the issue of modifying the stack.

```
asm(PSH CCW);
asm(SEI);
Variable++;
asm(PUL CCW);
```

This is ok as long as I don't need to do anything other than a simple variable++, but I don't like exiting a block with the stack modified.

Comment: On the HCS12 architecture this is performed through the `TAP`/`TPA` instructions to get and set the processor flags, which include interrupt control bits, along with `ORCC` to raise the I (and possibly X) bits which mask interrupts. This is usually done through inline assembly though the specifics depend on your compiler. Of course as a rule of thumb you'd be better off selectively masking only the interrupt source touching the variable in question.

Comment: Ok, I think that that gets me part way there.  I found the following macros in the project (I'm a late addition to the project and am unfamiliar with processor family) that seem to do part of what I want.

Comment: #define EnableInterrupts   _asm("andcc #$EF")

#define DisableInterrupts  _asm("orcc #$10")

Looks like bit 4 for the cc register acts as a Disable Interrupt when set to 1.  I see how to set it, but not how to get its current state.

Comment: BTW, I'm working in C with limited access to assembly.

Comment: That's where the `TPA` and `TAP` instructions for transferring the flags to the accumulator come in, likely combined with `STA`/`LDA` to the store/load the accumulator to a memory variable (or `PSHC`/`PULC` to save it on the stack but that's a scary thing to attempt in inline asm). See the S12CPUV2 reference manual for details, along with your compiler manual on how to access C variables from inline assembly. Again, unless your compiler or libraries happen to offer ready-made functions for the task you'll need to touch assembly, or at least tell us what compiler you are using.

Comment: I'm using Freescale's CodeWarrior for MCU 10.6.4 clearly with the S12Z toolchain from that release.  I agree that addressing stack variables is a scary thing from a C environment that you don't have complete details about. If you can help with a solution that uses a static variable, that would be great.

Comment: Ok, as a result of your hints, I found functions that will do what I want in the runtime code  (_PUSH_CC() and _POP_CC()) in rtshc08.c

Comment: I just realized that we may be talking at cross purposes here.  The  MC9S12ZVM isn't part of the HCS12 architecture.  (Registers D0 - D7 instead of A, B, D and things like TAP and TPA therefore don't exist)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are referring to the global interrupt mask. If so, then this is one way to disable it and then restore it to previous state:

```
static const uint8_t CCR_I_MASK = 0x10;

static uint8_t ccr;

void disable_interrupts (void)
{
  __asm PSHA;
  __asm TPA;                                     // transfer CCR to A
  __asm STA ccr;                                 // store CCR in RAM variable
  __asm PULA;
  __asm SEI;

}

void restore_interrupts (void)
{
  if((ccr & CCR_I_MASK) == 0)
  {
    __asm CLI;                                   // i was not set, clear it
  }
  else
  {
    ;                                            // i was set, do nothing
  }
}
```

`__asm` is specific to the Codewarrior compiler, with or without "strict ANSI" option set.

Comment: I had found something very similar to your disable interrupts routine.  The problem with it is that the compiler reject the syntax of the PSHA instruction and there doesn't seem to be a TPA instruction on the S12Z.  Still, I like the approach.

Comment: @Tom Both PSHA and TPA exist on HCS12, you are doing something wrong. What compiler error are you getting? The only difference between S08 and S12 seems to be the location of the `i` bit in the CCR, the mask needs to be 0x10 on S12. (I'll update the example so that it is compatible with S12)

Comment: I'm using the default compiler that comes with 10.6.4 of the CW for MCUs from Freescale.

Comment: PSHA = undefined identifier
STA = illegal assembly statement "expected mnemonic or label"
PULA = expected ;

Comment: Sorry, my comment about TPA was wrong, it is TAP that won't compile.

Comment: @Tom If it swallows some assembler instructions but whines about others, it sounds like the project is created for the wrong MCU. Codewarrior is one buggy mess nowadays after the Eclipse nuke, so I wouldn't rule out IDE bugs in the CW port of Eclipse.

Comment: I found the assembler manual at http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/S12ZCPU_RM_V1.pdf which has a rather different syntax and register set than the examples that I've been seeing.  I now have usable code that doesn't leave the stack in an altered state when exiting the block of assembly code.  I'll post this as AN answer to my question shortly

Comment: Up vote for this answer because it appears that it will work on some versions of the S12, just not on the S12Z

Comment: @Tom It is the same for all of the S12 family, since they share the same CPU core. Its assembler is even compatible with the older 68HC12.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92173/discussion-between-tom-and-lundin).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found an answer to my problem, with thanks to those who commented.

```
static volatile uint16_t v = 0u;
void testfunction(void);
void testfunction(void)
{
  static uint16_t L_CCR;
  asm( PSH D2 );
  asm( TFR CCW, D2);
  asm( ST D2, L_CCR );
  asm( PUL D2 ); 
  asm( SEI );
  v++;
  asm( PSH D2 );
  asm( LD D2, L_CCR );
  asm( TFR D2, CCW);
  asm( PUL D2 );

}
```